# Django I don't have a dictionary POST, just a field 'body'

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea

I'm writing an API (with out frameworks) and trying send POST from RESTClient
In body I write password=test&username=test and I don't have POST dictionary.

[image: without POST dict!!]

If I use intellij idea RESTful tool and write data in "Request Parametrs".

[image]

I have got POST dictionary

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: I don't know how to answer you. But I can give you a suggestion. **Learn how to inspect HTTP Header.**

Comment: Ohhh, content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Great, Now you've just solve your problem :) Pleased to help you. Let us know if you have other problem.